# What file types can you stream with a Flash Player?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I need to be able to stream as many different media files as possible, so .avi, .mpeg, .wav, .mp3 etc, i.e as many video and audio file types as possible.4
Do you know which i can do through flash? And do i do it the same way as i would a .flv?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Streaming .avi and .wav is highly problematic. They're not designed to be streamed, and they're also container formats, meaning they can hold ANY kind of audio/video data, which depend on appropriate codecs being present in the client-side player. If you push out an .avi which uses (says) Intel Indeo for video, it's unlikely to play on any modern system as Intel long ago terminated development/support for that codec.

Stick with .flv for video, and .mp3 for audio. Support for those is built into Flash.

Comment: Thanks - So if i needed to show these files online, how would you suggest getting about it?

Comment: Unless you can guarantee the wav/avi files use standard codecs that are present in all systems, don't use them. If you can't guarantee this, then transcode them to flv/mp3 and serve that instead.